# What happens during concurrent access with JPA and exclusive locks?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

We are currently doing a discussion on our architecture.

The idea is that we have a database and multiple processing units. One transaction does include the following steps:

1. Query an entry based on a flag
2. Request exclusive lock for this entry
3. Do the processing
4. Update the Flag and some other columns
5. Release lock and commit transaction

But what happens if the second processing unit queries an entry, while the first one does hold a lock?

Updating the flag during transaction does not do the job due to transaction isolation and [dirty read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write%E2%80%93read_conflict)

In my opinion the possible results on this situation are:

- The second processing unit gets the same entry and an exception is raised during the lockrequest
- The second one get the next available entry and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second processing unit gets the same entry.

However, whether the exception will be thrown or the lock acquisition will be blocked until the lock is released by the first transaction depends on the way you are asking for the lock in the second transaction (for example, with timeout or `NO WAIT` or something similar).

The second scenario (*The second one gets the next available entry*) is a bit harder to implement. Concurrent transactions are isolated from each other, so they basically see the same snapshot of data until one of them commits.

You can take a look at some database specific features, like [Oracle Advanced Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm), or you could change the approach you read data (for example, read them in batches and then dispatch the processing to multiple threads/transactions). All of this highly depends on what exactly you are solving, are there any processing order constraints, failure/rollback/retry handling, etc.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to get the next available entry?